# How can I determine where python pip is getting a --prefix=...?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

I am using pip for python installation from an anaconda environment (and the same happens outside the environment).  When I use pip, I always get something like:

```
Installing collected packages: pylev
Running setup.py install for pylev ...     Running command /home/sdavis2/.conda/envs/python3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-ao6tixgs/pylev/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-whv20bbp-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile \
--prefix=/data/CCRBioinfo/biowulf/local
```

Note the `--prefix` at the end of the line.  Everything gets installed to that prefix, and that is definitely not my intent.  Instead, I expect everything to be installed in the conda environment, and using easy_install actually gets that result.

I have entirely removed my ~/.pip directory and scoured my .profile, .bashrc, and .bash_profile scripts for anything setting anything related to python, pip, or PYTHONPATH.  Any ideas where else to look to figure out why this `--prefix` is always included?  I will mention that this is not something that my sysadmins have done, either, as the prefix path that is specified is actually my directory and not a "system" directory.

Comment: Anything under `.conda`?  `grep -r CCRBioinfo $HOME/.conda/*`

Comment: `grep -r CCRBioinfo $HOME/.conda/*` returns no matches.

Comment: Ok! Hmm. Anything look useful in `conda info -a`? Which pip are you running? `which pip` and `type pip` just to be sure.

Comment: Thx, @SimonFraser.   `(python3)[sdavis2@biowulf ~]$ which pip`
`~/.conda/envs/python3/bin/pip`
`(python3)[sdavis2@biowulf ~]$ type pip`
`pip is hashed (/home/sdavis2/.conda/envs/python3/bin/pip)`. `conda info -a` didn't turn up anything obvious.